# Printing values from a System.String[] using foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, string, wmi

My goal is to get the IP addresses alongside the NIC names,
Here is my sample code, I want to get the value of the IPAddress object which is of type `System.String[]`, I see a lot of internet post and try to copy their code for a `foreach loop`, but it is not working for me, what could be the problem?

I am still getting used to the `foreach` loop since it is new to me just this week

My error is highlighted at the `foreach` Error which is :

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ");

int ram = 1;
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
     if (obj["MACAddress"] != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("NIC #{0}:", ram));

         if (obj["IPAddress"] != null) // IPAddress is of type System.String[]
         {
             foreach (string s in obj["IPAddress"])
             { 
                 Console.WriteLine(s);         
             }   
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is telling  you that `obj["IPAddress"]` is returning an `object` and that `foreach` doesn't know how to iterate through an `object`.

Therefore, you must first cast your `obj` to an iterable collection :

```
 String[] addresses = (String[])obj["IPAddress"];
 foreach (string s in addresses)
 { 
     Console.WriteLine(s);         
 }
```

Taken from [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.

Hence the fact that `foreach` isn't supported for the `object` type.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark your question as resolved by accepting one of the answers.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for the reminder =) didn't know such a feature existed for the person who asked, cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert it into String Array first and then Change your code as below.

```
if (obj["IPAddress"] != null) // IPAddress is of type System.String[]
     {
        string[] newStringArray = (String[])obj["IPAddress"];
         foreach (string s in newStringArray )
         { 
             Console.WriteLine(s);         
         }
     }
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: Weird, I included System.Linq yet it the <code>ToArray()</code> does not appear, with this it gave me an idea from an old class and i just used the (string[])obj["IPAddress"]; instead, thanks man for the help =) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast `obj["IPAddress"]` explicitly into a `String[]` type.

Comment: Yup, i explicitly stated it like what luke said, thanks man =)